# How to prevent an input from being disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, disabled-input

I have an input field `<input>` with id **my-field** to which some plugin adds the attribute `disabled="disabled"` after the first escape.

This is a problem so i'm trying to keep that disabled attribute away from it with the code below:

```
var input = document.getElementById("my-field");
document.addEventListener("change", input, function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        input.disabled = false;
    }, 50)
});
```

but it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** as suggested below i corrected the boolean to have no "" but it's not working.

Comment: The *string* value "false" is not the same as the *boolean* value `false`.

Comment: corrected it thanks, but it's not working, it also threw error about the eventListener second parameter, so i've put the input var there instead, still no luck

Comment: The `addEventListener()` API does not work that way. You add listeners directly to elements. What you have above is how you'd do it with jQuery, sort-of, and you included jQuery as a tag in the question. If you're not really using jQuery, you should remove the tag.

Comment: that's right, long time i didnt code in js, i confused the jquery version, and you're correct I can't use jqeury i removed the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redefine the setAttribute method and disabled property in the input, something like:

```
function removeDisabled(input) {
    input.disabled = false;
    input.removeAttribute('disabled');
    Object.defineProperties(input, {
        disabled: {
            get: function() { return false; }
        },
        setAttribute: {
            value: function() {}
        }
    })
}

removeDisabled(document.getElementById('my-field'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it this way

> Vanilla Javascript

```
// Enable
document.getElementById("my-field").disabled = false;

// Disable
document.getElementById("my-field").disabled = true;
```

> JQuery

```
// Enable
$("#my-field").prop( "disabled", false );

// Disable
$("#my-field").prop( "disabled", true );
```

Comment: does .prop work for vanilla too? cause i don't have jquery at this time

Comment: Added the vanilla solution for you

Comment: Doesn't work, it's the same as my solution but without "" on boolean, as @Pointy suggested above

Comment: If your problem is overriding other plugin disabling input, then you should write `setTimeout` outside event listener because input change event will never get triggered if the input is getting disabled by default

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove Attribute, use the `removeAttribute` function like this:

```
document.querySelector('#my-field').removeAttribute('disabled')
```

As for your solution, I'd recommend listening to changes on the element, rather than guessing the timeout, something like this:

```
new MutationObserver(([{ attributeName, target }]) =>
        attributeName === 'disabled' && target.removeAttribute('disabled')
    ).observe(document.querySelector('#my-field'), { attributes: true });
```

Comment: tried that with getElementById instead of querySelector, no luck

Comment: @NathanBernard The function "getElementById", other than its longer and more cumbersome name, is not generic, and refers only to IDs. If  you'll want to use a selector that includes class or attribute, you will need to replace the entire function. In the case of "querySelector", control is more convenient, and only selector should replaced.

Comment: is your solution with Observer supposed to work straigth away? cause i tried it but didn't work (i obviously set the correct #id in the queryselector). thanks

Comment: @NathanBernard Look, you are passing the requested element as an argument to it. If this element is not in the DOM yet, then of course nothing will happen. If this ```document.querySelector('#my-field')``` returns ```null```, it won't work.

Comment: That's why i used the .addEventListener("change", input, [...] targetting the document, but as Pointy stated above i confused jquery with vanilla, so i'd need the equivalent of it in vanilla i guess

Answer (score 0):

$("#my-field").removeAttr("disabled");
document.getElementById("my-field").removeAttribute("disabled")

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to solve your problem

For enable:
$("#element").prop( "disabled", false );

For disable:
$("#element").prop( "disabled", true );